# Visual Studio Ultimate Load testing - Cannot add web performance test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Was hoping to use Visual Studio Ultimate trial to run load tests against the website being developed.  All tutorials and walkthroughs seem to point to my ability to go to 'add->Web performance test' from the project.  These nor any of the other Gui elements i've seen in youtube clips and the like appear here.

Is there anything that must be configured for me to utilize the load testing part of Visual Studio ultimate?

Thanks

Have tried:

- Using the test dropdown menu.
- Creating a new project
- Creating a new project of a different type.

The underlying issue I believe is that i already had a version of visual studio installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed visual studio ultimate on a seperate computer and everything ran as expected.
Uninstalled Ultimate on the computer running both ultimate and professional and re-installed the service pack.  This resolved the performance testing issue.